# Using tr command to encode text form a file

Tags: bash, unix

Im trying to change each character in a text file to the next character in the ASII table from space to ~. For example, A is replaced by B, z is replaced by [, etc. The encoding will wrap around so that tilde (~) will be replaced by space. Im sure this isnt the easiest way but this is what i currently have

```
tr ' !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~' '!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ' < mydata.txt
```

This gives me

```
-bash: !"#$%: event not found
```

Is there a quick fix that im not seeing or will this method not work? I need to use the tr command for this.

Comment: could you explain this `Im trying to change each character in a text file to the next character` ?

Comment: Sorry, tried to make it a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is you didn't map the embedded `'` in the first string, so things are a bit wonky.

```
tr ' !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~' '!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ' < mydata.txt
```

In the first line, you have a single quote after the `&`, which marks the end of the first single-quoted string. The parentheses and so on are outside any quote marks.  The back-quote is going to give you gyp too.  Then the single quote after `~` marks the start of a new single quoted string, then the next single quote is the end, so the second exclamation mark is outside any quotation marks, and hence gives you the error.

You need to use the sequence `'\''` to embed a single quote in a single-quoted string:

```
tr ' !"#$%&'\''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~' '!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ' < mydata.txt
```

That leaves the exclamation mark, back quotes, etc inside single quotes, as desired.

In the sequence `'…'\''…'`, the first single quote after the ellipsis terminates the current single quoted string, the backslash and single quote give a single quote, and then the last single quote resumes the single quoted string.

Note that you can write a simpler command than the one you used:

```
tr '\040-\176' '\041-\176\040'
```

with the additional benefit that you don't have any embedded single quotes, etc, to make things messy.  Plus you can see how to extend it to the accented characters in an 8-bit ISO 8859-x code set, etc.  Be wary of mapping newlines, but it will work admirably on control characters too.  It does make assumptions about the code set that your code does not. OTOH, if you mis-sequence characters in the written out version, you may get some interesting mis-mappings.  Or maybe the mis-mappings are desirable.  Anyway, this is an alternative notation that also works.